# Javascript / Select elements without a Class

Tags: javascript, select

I've got a Calendar-table (created as a Javascript Object). Its top row involves both the days of previous and current month. I marked the days of the current month with Class "Out". 
Now I need to select the days of the previous month in order to make a Statement
     ***if {The top table row has the cells without Class "Out", I don't want to show them***}
How can I do that using native Javascript? In other words it seems like I need an analogue of **.not()** in JQuery.

Comment: why not show all, and hide the ones with the class?

Comment: `table.querySelectorAll("td:not(.out)")`?

Comment: @ atmd It will make me rewrite a lot of code and make another logical chain which is much more difficult than what I am asking for.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah that works! Thank you! I had tried it before writing the question here, but I made a mistake because Console showed me Error.

Answer (score 2):

[`:not(simple-selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) is actually a valid selector that you can pass to `querySelector` (and it [is pretty well supported too](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

```
if (!document.querySelector(".your-table tr:first-child td:not(.Out)") {
  // Then we need to hide that row
}
```