# CSS selector for exact class name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a data scraper and I need to collect a certain class in a nodelist:

```
let renewButtons = document.querySelectorAll('a._7s5_._3-95._4jy0._4jy3._517h._51sy._42ft')
```

These renewButtons are enabled and clickable buttons. My issue arises with the disabled buttons on the page. Their class names are:

```
_7s5_ _3-95 _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft _42fr
```

which is the same class as the enabled buttons except for the _42fr class added at the end. Everytime I querySelectorAll I get a nodelist of both enabled and disabled buttons. Is there a way to specify selecting only the enabled buttons? (selecting a class that matches exactly and only the specified classes)

Comment: @MisterJojo yeah

Comment: `let renewButtons = document.querySelectorAll('a._7s5_._3-95._4jy0._4jy3._517h._51sy._42ft:not(._42fr)')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript / Select elements without a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908074/javascript-select-elements-without-a-class)

Comment: @ChrisG your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try the use of `pseudo` selectors.
These are not actualy selectors, but consider them like "meta" selectors that each browser usually knows how to handle.

In your case you would use the `:disabled` selector.

Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) for more info on this, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:enabled` in your query selector like in an example below:

```js
// will console only enabled `.btn` elements
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".btn:enabled"))
```

```html
<button class="btn">Enabled</button>
<button class="btn disabled" disabled>Disabled</button>
```